# How do i fix my code (singlylinkedlist) so that the function adds at the proper index?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to add "hello" at the index 0 but it it's added at index one, and also prints USA after that when it shouldn't. What's wrong with my add method? Is there something else that's wrong in the code that's causing this problem or is it just the add method? Any help is appreciated... The code of singlylinkedlist with the implementation is below...

```
 class SinglyLinkedList<E> { //---------------- nested Node class
 private static class Node<E> { private E element;
 private Node<E> next;
 public Node(E e, Node<E> n) {
 element = e;
next = n; }
 public E getElement() {
 return element;
 }
 public Node<E> getNext() {
return next;
 }
 public void setNext(Node<E> n) {
next = n;
} }
 private Node<E> head = null;
 private Node<E> tail = null;
 private int size = 0;
 public SinglyLinkedList() { }
 public int size() { return size; }
 public boolean isEmpty() { return size == 0; }
 public E first() {
 if (isEmpty()) return null; return head.getElement();
 }
 public E last() {
 if (isEmpty()) return null;
 return tail.getElement(); }
 // update methods
 public void addFirst(E e) {
 head = new Node<>(e, head);
 if (size == 0)
 tail = head;
 size++;
 }
 public void addLast(E e) {
 Node<E> newest = new Node<>(e, null);
 if (isEmpty( ))
 head = newest;
 else
 tail.setNext(newest);
 tail = newest;
size++;
 }
 public E removeFirst() {
 if (isEmpty())
 return null;
 E answer = head.getElement();
 head = head.getNext();
 size--;
 if (size == 0)
 tail = null;
 return answer;
 }
 public void printLinkedList() {
     Node<E> temp = head;
     for(int i = 0; i< size; i++) {
         System.out.println(temp.getElement());
         temp = temp.next;
     }
 } 
 public void removeLast() {
     tail = null;
     size--;
 }


 public void remove(int index) {
 //Node<E> newest = new Node(e, null);
 Node<E> current = head;
 if (index == 0) {
 removeFirst();
 }
 else {
 for (int i = 0; i<index -1; i++) {
 //current = current.next;
 current = current.getNext();
}
 current.next = current.next.next;
 }
 size--;
}
 public void add(int index, E e) {
     Node<E> current = head;
     Node newNode = new Node(e, null);
        for(int i = 0; i< index; i++) {
            current = current.next;
        }
     current.next = newNode;
     newNode.next = current;
     size++;
 } 

 }
public class SinglyLinkedListTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SinglyLinkedList<String>  list = new SinglyLinkedList();
        list.addLast("USA");
        list.addLast("America");
        list.addLast("portugal");
        System.out.println(" ");
        list.printLinkedList();
        //list.remove(2);
        System.out.println(" ");
        list.printLinkedList();
        list.removeLast();
        System.out.println(" ");
        list.printLinkedList();
        list.add(0, "hello");
        System.out.println(" ");
        list.printLinkedList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use ArrayList? You're complicating things in a very bad way man

Answer (score 0):

There a two mistakes:

1. at index 0 you need to replace `head`
2. `current` points to `newNode` and `newNode` points to `current`

Fixed code:

```
public void add(int index, E e) {
    Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(e, null);
    if(index == 0) {
        newNode.next = head;
        head = newNode;
    } else {
        Node<E> current = head;
        for(int i = 1; i< index; i++) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        Node<E> tmp = current.next;
        current.next = newNode;
        newNode.next = tmp;
    }
    size++;
}
```